# Command in Ubuntu to access start page for Broadcom

Tags: command-line, root, broadcom

I have Ubuntu installed with Broadcom and need to run start page of Broadcom to install a driver.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Comment: You mention have Ubuntu installed, but no clues as to which Ubuntu product, or which release of that product. For specific advice, you need to provide details.